# Debug info from Symfony sfMailer regarding sending a mail

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, swiftmailer

I need to log result of sending an e-mail message by sfMailer in Symfony 1.4

The message is to be sent when user submits a form which includes his contact e-mail address.

In case of failure (sending the mail) I should log his e-mail address using logger. That is pretty clear to me.

What I still don't get is how to get an "update" from sfMailer about whether the sending was success? 
Something that returns true or false if possible.

Web debug toolbar is nice but it does not help here.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the doc](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html):

> When using send() the message will be sent just like it would be sent if you used your mail client. **An integer is returned which includes the number of successful recipients.** If none of the recipients could be sent to then zero will be returned, which equates to a boolean false. If you set two To: recipients and three Bcc: recipients in the message and all of the recipients are delivered to successfully then the value 5 will be returned.

Which result in:

```
// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);

// or in a symfony action
$result = $this->getMailer()->send($message);
```